# How to add new value in collection laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the following loop where I try to add a new value:

```
 foreach ($pro->sig()->get() as $key => $sig) {
            $sig->val = 2;
        }
```

When I print the output of `$pro->sig()` I don't have the new value `$sig->val`

Comment: Did u try $sig->attributes['val'] = 2?

Comment: $collection->map() to update and return each new item [example](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/add-key-value-to-current-object-in-eloquent-collection), [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-map)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you have a collection you can use `push` or `put` method.

Example with put:

```
$collection = collect(['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk']);

$collection->put('test', 'test');

$collection->all();
```

The output will be:

```
['product_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Desk', 'test' => 'test']
```

Example with push:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4]);

$collection->push(5);

$collection->all();
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-push

**update**
Reference for 5.8: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-push

Answer (score 14):

In my example, I tried like the below

```
foreach ($user->emails as $key => $email) {
   $email->test = "test";
}
return $user->emails;
```

It outputs like,

```
  {
    "id": 76,
    "user_id": 5,
    "additional_email": "test@test.com",
    "test": "test"
  }
```

Please try like this.

Answer (score 5):

```
$users = User::find(1);

$user->objectName = " Value ";
```

that works fine if you just need to push another object in the collection by eloquent.